# How can I get a Flutter's texture from native plugin? (flutter => native. Not native => flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit

I'd like to use a Flutter's texture by native plugin on Android/iOS. So, I'd like to pass a Flutter's texture to native plugin. (flutter => native)

My first plan is:

1. Use the camera plugin to get a previewed image.

   - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera
2. Pass the image(textureId or byte array) to native plugin.
3. Use the image in native code. (I'll create this plugin.)

But, I couldn't pass the image to native easily.

I didn't know how to get an image in native code by Flutter's `textureId`.

1. I know a texture will be able to be passed to Flutter code from native code. (native => flutter)
2. I know I can take a screenshot and pass the byte array to native image.
   But I think it is not effective.

I already checked the issue, but I think it is good to combine some plugins. So, I would like to use the camera plugin to get an image and pass it to another plugin if it is possible.

> Using a live camera view with ML Kit plugin
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19274

Could you please give me ideas?